# Printable Paging MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, asp-classic

I have a question maybe someone could help me with. I have a Ticket Tracking system that was created with a MySQL database. I need to print out ticket streams of records for a client but the problem is so of the tickets threads he wants has like 150 records and its setup for paging so to print one page it will only give me like 25 records.

I need a way to making it printer friendly layout so my client can print out all threads even if there paging in a nice format and layout to hand off to his clients. Does anyone know of any object, product, or place that could do this? Please keep in mind The solution needs to be web based and would prefer something in Classic ASP if possible but open to ALL suggestions. The site was developed years ago and is using Classic ASP.

Thanks for your help!!!

Frank G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to look into finding a pagination tool for ASP along with limiting the number of records pulled from the MYSQL database.  Here is an example of the MYSQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM `tickets` LIMIT 50, 30
```

Where the first number is the offset (skip the first 50 rows) and the second number is the limit (30 rows)

I don't know ASP so this is all I can offer.  Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I know how to do the paging in general when displaying the records on the web browser. But don't know how to handle it when it comes to printing them. Do I just display all the records on one page and give them a print button? As for coding and designing the printable page I can handle that.

Comment: I honestly have never done anything with printer formats, but I found this on Google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446876/trapping-ctrl-p-in-javascript-and-calling-a-custom-function-for-printing  It looks like you can use some CSS tricks to only print certain things when the user hits ctrl + p or prints the page.  So you could probably hide what you don't want and just display the records and print it out.